# JSON in Map apex code

Tags: apex, json

```
{
    "RecordCount": 1,
    "ProspectActivities": [
        {
            "Id": "3f4fffc2-f82f-11e6-8e85-22000b084956",
            "EventCode": 30,
            "EventName": "Sales Activity",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Key": "Currency",
                    "Value": "$"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "OrderValue",
                    "Value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "SalesData",
                    "Value": "{keyvalueinfo}"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How to create Map from this response?

Comment: This json response is not valid. Please check.

Comment: Are you trying to get the Data node in a Map?

Comment: Yes exactly  @SarojBera

Comment: @user40665 Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Json class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm).

There's a `deserializeUntyped(jsonString)` method which deserialize Json in a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) heroku app to generate the class. Your generated class should look like this.

Class generated by JSON2Apex heroku app

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class JSON2Apex {

    public Integer RecordCount;
    public List<ProspectActivities> ProspectActivities;

    public class Data {
        public String Key;
        public String Value;
    }

    public class ProspectActivities {
        public String Id;
        public Integer EventCode;
        public String EventName;
        public List<Data> Data;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this class to deserialize the JSON String like this.

```
JSON2Apex obj = JSON2Apex.parse(json);
```

> To get the Data node in a Map you can follow the the below code.

```
JSON2Apex obj = JSON2Apex.parse(json);
List<JSON2Apex.ProspectActivities> dtl = obj.ProspectActivities;
System.debug(dtl.size());
JSON2Apex.ProspectActivities pa = (JSON2Apex.ProspectActivities)dtl.get(0);
List<JSON2Apex.Data> lstdata = pa.Data;
System.debug(lstdata.size());
Map<String,String> mapData = new Map<String,String>();
for(JSON2Apex.Data d:lstdata){
    mapData.put(d.Key,d.Value);
}
System.debug(mapData);
```

Comment: How can i get it as List<Map<String,String>>